# privacy url and suburb fields added in registration page not showing in nop commerce project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I'm new to nop commerce. Doing changes in registration page, like wanted to add new code for pop up in the privacy url (tested with a plain href code) and added a suburb field in the address section. For new field added code for all related files, db. Build succeeded, but the changes not shown up. The previous url keep coming, suburb field not shown up. The main file is Register.cshtml. No errors to chase up. What I'm doing wrong. Please advise.

I'm using 3.1 ver of nop commerceand visual studio 2012.

Comment: The reasons can be: 1st you did not place your changes at the right place, 2nd you did not deploy your changes properly. However to decide which one is it, it would be nice to see the code.

Comment: Code for url change is

Comment: Code is  <div class="accept-privacy-policy"><input id="accept-privacy-policy" type="checkbox" name="accept-privacy-policy" /> <label for="accept-privacy-policy">I accept privacy policy</label> <a href="#"> (read)</a></div>  And Old code is <div class="accept-privacy-policy"><input id="accept-privacy-policy" type="checkbox" name="accept-privacy-policy" /><label for="accept-privacy-policy">@T("Account.Fields.AcceptPrivacyPolicy")</label><a class="read" href='@Url.RouteUrl("Topic", new { SystemName = "privacyinfo" })'>@T("Account.Fields.AcceptPrivacyPolicy.Read")</a></div>

Comment: I'm running the code locally pointing DB in SQL server instance in local. Default location in IIS server.

Comment: Also I am using the IIS express that comes with Visual Studio 2012 and that is running the project. Is that a problem? Do I have to install IIS 7 and deploy it?

Comment: The actual url http://localhost:2451/t/privacyinfo not showing, it redirects to sitehomepage. Where as if logged in it shows. how to remove access on this page?

Answer (score 0):

IIS Express is just fine. If you just replaced the old code with your new one and started the project from VS it should be displayed. Make sure the page is not cached, delete browser cache.

In order to add a new field to the form you should modify several parts of the application.

1. Add the suburb attribute name to SystemCustomerAttributeNames
2. Add the save and load logic to CustomerController
3. Modify the corresponding view models (RegisterModel.cs, AddressModel.cs)
4. Modify the corresponding views where you want to display the field (Register.cshtml, Addresses.cshtml)